# searching for old chemfig versions

Tags: chemfig, ctan

I would like to have older chemfig version packages. Unfortunately ctan has only the last version. I would especially need versions 1.3, 1.31, 1.32, 1.33, 1.34, 1.4, 1.41. If someone has any of these or other old version please let me know.

Comment: You could look through historic texlive versions and see which versions they got there https://www.tug.org/historic/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than CTAN, which does not keep a history of packages, I would use the [TeX Live SVN](https://tug.org/texlive/svn/) to track older package versions. You can access this via the web and look over [the `chemfig` directory](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/chemfig/) to find what you need. For exampl3, v1.33 is [commit 49043](https://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=49043).